# install mod_proxy_html.so on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I have a *MacBook*, I have XAMPP installed and trying to add mod_poxy_html module to apache of XAMPP.

Any idea how to do that? I did not find any useful information on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is included with xampp for mac but if it is you just have to open your httpd.conf and uncomment the module you want to enable.

You also have to restart apache in order to see changes.

You should have asked this question at serverfault i think.

Comment: I don't see that module on httpd.conf, so I had to download it from internet and follow this link to install it http://www.sysdigg.com/how-to-install-apache-mod_proxy_html-module-on-centos but that link is not helpful when it comes to xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I am using linux/ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) and I have the same problem. I see in `/opt/lampp/modules` all the available modules. `mod_proxy_html.so` is *not* there.

In `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` the `LoadModule` section has also no load for this module.

I will try to find more info about it and update this answer if I find the solution.

UPDATE 1:
Here is a link for some support on it: https://web.archive.org/web/20160224140148/https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache (bullet: 
"22. How to add mod_proxy_html module in Apache?") - aparently this is product specific and has to be compiled into mod. For Xampp I could not do it